# Where can I find practice problems for introductory differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, self-learning

I am currently watching N. J. Wildberger's introductory differential geometry lecture series on youtube, and while he offers the odd problem to solve, I would like to get (a lot) more practice. Are there any really good resources, preferably workbook(s), for people looking to concretize their understanding of undergraduate level differential geometry?

Comment: A pretty good set of notes with problems is here: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~petersen/DGnotes.pdf

Comment: Ted Shifrin's notes has lots of nice things: http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the plug, @IvoTerek, but that link is outdated. Please see my profile for the link to the current version.